# Enforce (almost) immediate release of memory to OS

Tags: c++, cgroups

In cgroups version 2 we have the memory.high and memory.max config files. When the group's memory consumption exceeds or approaches these values cgroups will take measures e.g. to release allocated and already freed memory from the group to the OS and report a lower memory use in memory.current.

Is there a way to enforce release of memory by API or else, before those barriers are reached? E.g. I want to trigger a high memory event in certain situations inside my application at times.

I was trying jemalloc but it seems jemalloc and cgroups don't play nice inside a container.